# In an acute angled triangle with angles $A,B$ and $C$, prove that $\left(\frac{\sin A}{A} + \frac{\sin B}{B} + \frac{\sin C}{C} \right)> \frac6\pi$

Tags: inequality, triangles

In an Acute Angled Triangle Prove That : -

$$\left(\frac{\sin A}{A} + \frac{\sin B}{B} + \frac{\sin C}{C} \right)> \frac{6}{\pi}$$

A , B , C represent the angles of the triangle.

Edit:

I wasn’t able to think of a direct approach so I assumed it to be a equilateral Triangle (we get some few inequalities by this method) but that didn’t work ...

Comment: I solved your problem. Show please your attempts and I'll show my solution.

Comment: I have edited the question showing my attempts ...I have never solved a question where we have direct Angle Mention so I am a bit perplexed...So i have tried substituting values ...A hint is much appreciated!

Comment: Show you trying in the general. Maybe you tried to use the Jensen's inequality. Show, why it does not help.

Comment: I am afraid that I don’t have any knowledge regarding “ jensen inequality “...my calculus course hasn’t yet started

Comment: I got an infimum of $\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{\sin{A}}{A}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's actually quite simple. The sinc function $\frac{\sin x}x$ is monotonically decreasing and positive on $[0,\pi/2]$; going from $1$ at $x=0$ to $\frac2\pi$ at $x=\frac\pi2$. So $\frac{\sin x}x>\frac2\pi$ for each angle of the *acute* triangle, and the sum must be strictly greater than $\frac6\pi$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $$f(x) = \frac{\sin x}{x}, \quad x \in \left[0, \frac{\pi}{2}\right].$$
We have
$$f'(x) = \frac{x \cos x - \sin x}{x^2} = \frac{g(x)}{x^2},$$
and
$$g'(x)= - x\sin x < 0.$$
So $g(x) < g(0) = 0,$ deduced $f'(x) < 0,$ or
$$f(x) > f\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right) = \frac{2}{\pi}.$$
Therefore
$$\frac{\sin A}{A} + \frac{\sin B}{B} + \frac{\sin C}{C} > \frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi}+\frac{2}{\pi} = \frac{6}{\pi}.$$

Answer (score 1):

We can effectively use the graph of this function for this problem.

The graph of $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ for $x$ belongs to $[0,\pi]$

[image]

Assume the three points $(A,\frac{\sin A}{A}),(B,\frac{\sin B}{B}),(C,\frac{\sin C}{C})$ on the graph. The centroid of this triangle is:$$\left(\frac{\left(A+B+C\right)}{3},\frac{\left(\frac{\sin A}{A}+\frac{\sin B}{B}+\frac{\sin C}{C}\right)}{3}\right)$$

We know that $A+B+C=\pi$ so, the Centroid lies on the line $x=\frac{\pi}{3}$

Graphically,
[image]

The centroid lies on the blue line. Also, as the graph is concave down, So the triangleformed always remains below the curve. Hence the centroid always remains below the curve. Its maximum y-coordinate will be when the centroid lies exactly on the curve.

For this to happen, all three points must coincide at $\left(\frac{\pi}{3},\frac{\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{3}\right)}{3}\right)$

So your maximum occurs when $A=B=C=\frac{\pi}{3}$. Hence:
$$(\frac{\sin A}{A} + \frac{\sin B}{B} + \frac{\sin C}{C} )> \frac{6}{\pi}$$

Comment: The visibility of the triangle is poor in the graph due to its low concavity. Please stress your eyes a bit to understand it. Thanks