# If $x,y, z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$ then prove that $\frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z≥9$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Can some please help me out with this question?
I tried it in this way
Note that  $a,b>0$  then  $a≥b\iff\frac 1a≤\frac1b$ .

So it is sufficient to prove  $\frac {1}{1/x+1/y+1/z}\leq\frac 19$ .

Comment: Do you know AM-HM?

Answer (score 1):

By AM-HM, we have $\frac 13=\frac {x+y+z}3\geq\frac 3{1/x+1/y+1/z}$, then $\frac 1x+\frac 1y+\frac 1z\geq9$. Equality holds only if $x=y=z=\frac 13$.

Comment: How did you know what he was asking?

Comment: @user2661923 I thought it was "obvious" (+1). Jokes aside, it was the only interpretation that A) occurred to me and B) made sense in that it matched  a correct claim. My guess is that it is also a duplicate of an older question, but in my opinion it is the duty of the ultra high rep users frequenting these tags to look for the best one.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I have an interesting graphical solution to this. A similar approach is used [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3825225/823370)

The graph of $y=\frac1x$ looks like this:

[image]

I am changing the scale on x-axis for a better look.

Now consider the points $(x,\frac1x)$, $(y,\frac1y)$, $(z,\frac1z)$. The centroid of the triangle formed lies on the line $x=\frac13$ because $x+y+z=1$. Due to the concavity of the graph, the triangle formed will always be above the graph, and hence, thee centroid will also be above it.

[image]

So the least value of the ordinate of the centroid would be when all three points coincide and the centroid lands on the graph. In all other cases it will be above the graph.

Thus you obtain the least value when all the numbers are equal

Answer (score 0):

> If $x,y,z>0$ and $x+y+z=1$, then prove that
> \begin{align}\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z\ge9 \tag{1}\label{1}. \end{align}

Alternatively, using [Ravi substitution](https://brilliant.org/wiki/ravi-substitution/),
where the triplet $a, b, c$ represents the sides of a valid triangle
with semiperimeter $\rho$, inradius $r$ and circumradius $R$,

\begin{align}
x&=\rho-a
,\quad
y=\rho-b
,\quad
z=\rho-c
\tag{2}\label{2}
,
\end{align}

\eqref{1} becomes

\begin{align}
\frac{3\rho^2-2(a+c+b)\,\rho+(ab+bc+ac)}
{\rho^3-(a+b+c)\rho^2+(ab+bc+ac)\,\rho-abc}
&\ge9
\tag{3}\label{3}
,\\
\frac{3\rho^2-2\,(2\rho)\,\rho+(\rho^2+r^2+4rR)}
{\rho^3-(2\,\rho)\rho^2+(\rho^2+r^2+4rR)\,\rho-4\rho r R}
-9
&\ge0
\tag{4}\label{4}
,
\end{align}

\begin{align} 
\frac{4R+r-9\rho r}{\rho r}
&\ge0
\tag{5}\label{5}
.
\end{align}

Since $\rho=x+y+z=1$,
\eqref{5} simplifies to

\begin{align} 
R-2r&\ge0
\tag{6}\label{6}
,
\end{align}

which always holds for a valid triangle.
The equality corresponds only to the equilateral triangle,
$a=b=c$, that is, $x=y=z=\tfrac13$
in the original \eqref{1}.